# Update fields without using PB or WF

Tags: trigger, workflow, process-builder

I am trying to update a field on a master object based on couple of values{criteria needs to be if Status = Approved on the header - thats when it should fire, then check if Y(at line level) is equal to 'Y' and then come back to header and update Z ='z'} .

I don't want this to fire on creation/edition of the record but rather when the particular criteria met(In my case as soon as Status=Approved). I understand I can use WF/PB with the criteria to fire even when the record is Edited but:

1. that would mean it would fire off everytime and I just want it to fire the only first time when the record status = Approved and not after that.
2. Somehow change in status is not counted as an Edit so my PB ignores it all together and does not fire. But if I go in and manually edit any field it fires without any issue. *How can I make it fire with just the status change on field level via an automated process.*

Am I over-complicating this? Do I need to use trigger?

Comment: What process is changing the status? If PB doesn't fire I would think Apex Trigger wouldn't either.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether you're using Process Builder or Workflow Rules, you can choose an option to fire the action of the PB/WR only if it's edited to meet the criteria you've established.

This ensures that the action does not take place on *any* edit, but only edits that move the record from a state of not meeting the criteria (such as Status = null) to one that does meet the criteria (such as Status = Approved).

Your point (2) is likely an indicator that there is an issue with the criteria on your Process. While there are a handful of circumstances where automation doesn't go off in response to record changes, this does not sound like one of them.

Comment: They also both have a way to check if a field changed.